# Best practice of handling hbase connection and table in java?

Tags: hbase

I'm using hbase-client 1.2.3, I saw there is a comment in Connection.getTable() method:

> - Retrieve a Table implementation for accessing a table.
> - The returned Table is not thread safe, a new instance should be
>     created for each using thread.
> - This is a lightweight operation, pooling or caching of the
>     returned Table
> - is neither required nor desired.

So I start wondering what's the best practice to handle connection and table?

For example, I have a main class, will start several threads, let's call A,B,C...

Now I call "Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection();" in the main method, and pass the connection to each thread as a param to each thread. And then init Table class in each thread.

I want to know is this the best way? Will it cause some threadsafe or efficiency or any other problems?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Connection.html):

> Connection creation is a heavy-weight operation. Connection implementations are thread-safe, so that the client can create a connection once, and share it with different threads. Table and Admin instances, on the other hand, are light-weight and are not thread-safe. **Typically, a single connection per client application is instantiated and every thread will obtain its own Table instance**. Caching or pooling of Table and Admin is not recommended.

So I would suggest that you initialize a connection only once and a new table every time it's required.

Sample Code:

```java
//initialize connection
Configuration hBaseConfig = HBaseConfiguration.create();
Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hBaseConfig);

//initialize table
try (Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("table-name"))) {
    //use table
}
```